# The best way to represent big organizational structure in browser in the most efficient way

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest, web

colleagues! We are developing a web application which has functionality to represent the organizational structure of current organization(a bank, for example). Organizational structure is represented as a parent-child relationships where each node has only one parent and each parent may have zero or more children. When the amount of entities(orgUnits) was comparable small, about 500 entities, our old method worked well. Generally, we used recursion to get all parent-child entities and passed it as a JSON document to browser where frontend part parsed this document and rendered it for user. Problems started when we uploaded the organizational structure of another organization(another bank) and had 6000 active orgUnits. Obviously fetching all orgUnits was not an option. We started to use request param *depth* to control recursion level but it didn't solve the problem of fetching child entities because each parent can have one or more children. For example, we had a parent orgUnit that had 100 children and any of this child could have one or more children. This method also loaded all orgUnits on this level even if it wasn't necessary. Right now i'm looking for solution that will keep number of orgUnits per HTTP request relatively small and browser won't freeze while rendering it. My idea is simple:

1. Paginate results somehow;
2. Only return additional child orgUnits when user wants it;

Our OrgUnitDTO looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "a4f51de5-36f3-258c-232d-3d617c07fefc",
  "extId": null,
  "type": "OrgUnit",
  "orgId": "99beadc8-831a-f6ab-fee9-11143d43ccd1",
  "parentId": "99beadc8-831a-f6ab-fee9-11143d43ccd1",
  "code": "second-level-test-department",
  "name": "name",
  "note": "note",
  "manager": null,
  "children": [], // children property has objects of the same type
  "createdBy": "userName",
  "updatedBy": "userName",
  "createdAt": "2020-09-04T06:23:53.793Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-09-04T06:23:53.795Z",
  "sortOrder": 0,
  "isManager": false
}
```

That's how it looks in GUI:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qsxj.png)

I'm looking for your suggestions for backend and frontend as well!

In case it matters we use Spring-Boot and Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is not a matter of framework used or technology.
Your question is more about the solution.

**Rule of thumb**: A human can interact only with few data at a time, so don't fetch or display a lot of data, is useless and slow.

I've dealt with a similar problem in the past and solved this way, but there may be better solutions of course:

1. I've created a backend function that a client can call to fill the page the first time is loaded so that you can get the first N levels of depth with an integer parameter (ie. 2 or 3) starting from a node of the tree (null if you want to start from the top).
2. I've added a search function (both on FE and BE) to let the user jump immediately to a position he already knows (ie. an employee name): the function returns only the JSON of the nodes that are composing the path to the founded node. Other nodes can be expanded with a [+] button or something like that, just to be hyperfast and concise in outputting data. Usually, if you search for a person in an org chart, you want to know immediately who are his bosses and nothing else.
3. Children for each node were not so many in my case, so I've not optimized here, but in your case, you can implement lazy loading of data with pagination if you have more than X children at the same level. You can use a \/ icon to load more nodes when the user clicks or you can do it automagically when the user scrolls down the page. It is up to you. It is up to you decide also the number of nodes to load after paging. You can make this responsive, you load more nodes if the screen has space to display them.
4. To open each subsequent node call the function you used at the first-page loading only when the user clicks on the [+] passing the current node id and 1 as parameters to specify you want only one level more.
5. To implement the FE part I've used [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) and [jstreegrid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid).

**General hint**: choose the FE part library first, THEN create backend functions, it will be easier and you'll make fewer refactorings.